# C++ How can I access to an inner enum class?

Tags: c++, class, enums

I am facing a problem in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
 class Apple{
public:
    int price = 100;
    enum class color {
    red =1, green, yellow
    };



};
int main() {
 Apple apple;
 std::cout << Apple::color::green << std::endl;

}
```

When I try to compile this code following message appears:

> [Error] 'Apple::color' is not a class or namespace

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using? Enum classes are supported from c++11. When I ran your example it gave me a  "no operator "<<" matches these operands"  error. (In VS15 - vc140)

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? ``\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

P0W's answer is correct on both counts, but in case you simply want to output the underlying value, then it may be simpler to cast rather than overload the insertion operator.

```
using enum_type = std::underlying_type<Apple::color>::type;
enum_type value = (enum_type)Apple::color::green;
std::cout << value << '\n';
```

Comment: You could at least use `static_cast` rather than a C-style cast in your example

Comment: @kim366 I could, but I also don't have to. I find a C-style cast to be easier to read and given the context there is no chance to misunderstand the type of conversion.

Answer (score 4):

1. Looks like you're using a pre C++11 compiler  or c++11 flag is not enabled.
2. After using correct c++11 flag, you will have to overload `operator <<`

   ```
   friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& os, const color& c )
   {
     /* ... */
     return os;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

- Enable `c++11` cause `enum class` are a c++11 feature suing the --`std=c++11` compiler flag.
- Overload the `<<` operator if you want to `cout` an `Apple::color`

Something like the following should work:

```
#include <iostream>

class Apple {
 public:
  int price = 100;
  enum class color { red = 1, green, yellow };
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Apple::color& c) {
  if (c == Apple::color::red) std::cout << "Red\n";
  if (c == Apple::color::green) std::cout << "Green\n";
  if (c == Apple::color::yellow) std::cout << "Yellow\n";
  return os;
}

int main() {
  Apple apple;
  std::cout << Apple::color::green << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `enum class` your compiler has to support C++11. This can be for example achieved by appending a `-std=c++11` after your clang or g++ build command if you are using those. New versions of Visual Studio enable C++11 automatically.

The error that you should be getting is `no operator "<<`, as pointed out by @pvl, since `enum class` doesn't convert to anything implicitly and therefore won't output an integer value.

Comment: A cast is always explicit -- it's something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The problem is that there is no **implicit conversion**.