# Accessing Variant Elements by Index: What does the documentation tell me?

Tags: c++, variant, code-documentation

The following code works well on my computer:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::variant<double, std::string> var;
    var = 20;
    if (std::get_if<0>(&var))
        std::cout << "a double\n";
    else if (std::get_if<1>(&var))
        std::cout << "a string\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I create a `variant` containing either a `double` or a  `string` and then check if the variant holds an element of either type using [std::get_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if) through an index. In constrast, the following code does not compile:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::variant<double, std::string> var;
    var = 20;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if (std::get_if<i>(&var))
            std::cout << i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am still trying to learn `c++`, and the documentation is at times still incomprehensible to me.

Can somebody kindly explain how the documentation I linked informs me that I cannot use a `size_t` (or an `int`) element to check if the variant holds a particular type?

Second, is there a way to check type membership of a variant in a loop at all?

Comment: The second code doesn't compile because a template argument (even if it's for a template value parameter) must be known at compile time. Constant integers like `0` or `1` are but a variable value is not. Hence, `if (std::get_if<i>(&var))` will not compile because `i` is no  valid template argument.

Comment: Concerning the last question, this might be of help: [SO: How to make a safer C++ variant visitor, similar to switch statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45708407/7478597)

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081573/passing-a-variable-as-a-template-argument

Comment: The TL;DR of this is that a function template is not a function. It's a template for generating functions. Function generation can only happen during compilation and thus any template arguments must be compile-time constants.

Comment: Yet another approach for your code: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77c62594ef27dab8).

Comment: thank you very much, Scheff and Nikos ! I learned a lot from your comments.